# Dropwizard Catch-All Error Page

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, dropwizard

I'm trying to create an Error Resource that will show the exact same view for all 300-599 error codes. I've got it mostly working, with the exception of erroneous POST requests. The error I get is,

```
WARN  [2017-09-06 23:56:51,475] org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler: Error page loop /error
```

It seems like something is off in my ErrorResource logic, but I can't seem to put my finger on it.

Here is the ErrorResource class...

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

import com.project.views.ErrorView;

import java.net.URI;

@Path("/error/")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public class ErrorResource {
    private String appName;
    @Context
    UriInfo uri;

    public ErrorResource(String appName) {
        this.appName = appName;
    }

    @POST
    public Response errorPost() {
        URI redirectUri = uri.getBaseUri();
        return Response.seeOther(redirectUri).build();
    }

    @GET
    public ErrorView error() {
        return new ErrorView(appName);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/404/")
    public Response error404() {
        return Response.status(404).entity(new ErrorView(appName)).build();
    }
}
```

The errorPost() function is what's giving me trouble. The idea was to do at 301 redirect back to the same page, ostensibly performing a GET request which gets caught by the regular error() function. My Application Class shows that I'm registering the error handler to catch all 300-599's...

```
public class WebAppApplication extends Application<WebAppConfiguration> {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new WebAppApplication().run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(Bootstrap<WebAppConfiguration> bootstrap) {
        bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/www", "/static"));
        bootstrap.addBundle(new ViewBundle());
    }

    @Override
    public void run(WebAppConfiguration config, Environment environment) {
        /* Error Handling */
        ErrorPageErrorHandler errorHandler = new ErrorPageErrorHandler();
        errorHandler.addErrorPage(300,403,"/error");
        errorHandler.addErrorPage(404, "/error/404");
        errorHandler.addErrorPage(405,599,"/error");

        /* Resources */
        final HomeResource homeResource = new HomeResource(config.getAppName());
        final ErrorResource errorResource = new ErrorResource(config.getAppName());

        /* Environment Registration */
        environment.getApplicationContext().setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
        environment.jersey().register(homeResource);
    }
}
```

And nothing too crazy in the Error view

```
public class ErrorView extends View {
    private String appName;

    public ErrorView(String appName) {
        super("pageError.mustache");
        this.appName = appName;
    }

    public String getAppName() {
        return XSS.htmlEncode(appName);
    }
}
```

The ErrorView mustache template only really contains a message, the navbar, and meta refresh HTML tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=/" />
```

But issuing an erronous POST request to the "/input/" (or any) endpoint throws that "page loop" error, and returns this in the browser...

Browser Screenshot:

[image: Browser Screenshot]

Making this a catch-all error message would help to keep the code base clean, will be helpful to the user, and maintains the website branding even in a unexpected failure.

I appreciate any insight the community might have, and preemptive "thank you" for the advice!

Comment: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS is what you meant?

Comment: Don't think I ever saw that error